# What is the best and fastest way to query lots of data with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, performance, mongoose

I want to do the following:

I have more then 10,000 users in my db.

I need to send all of them an event that will change a value in their document,

For example:

```
user:{
   money:10,
   skill : 5,
   mood  : 1
}
```

So this is what i want to avoid because it's a memory and a cpu hell:

```
User.find({}).exec(function(err,users){
   users.forEach(function(user){
      if(user.money < 10){
         user.money += 5 * (some other params or something);
      }
      user.save();
   });
);
```

Also i need to extract the id of each user who have money lower than 10 and send him a push.... so i cant use just "update","inc" or "set"

This code crashes my server, How can i make it better?  should i use async? if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a single `update` with the [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc) operator and the `{multi: true}` option so that it's applied to all matching docs:

```
User.update(
    {money: {$lt: 10}}, 
    {$inc: {money: 5 * (some other params or something)}}, 
    {multi: true}, 
    function(err, num) { ... });
```

If your updates are such that each doc needs special handling based on its content, you can use a [streaming](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream_QueryStream) approach to limit the number of docs in memory at any one time:

```
var stream = User.find({}).stream();
stream.on('data', function(user) {
    stream.pause();
    if(user.money < 10){
       user.money += 5 * (some other params or something);
    }
    // More document-specific updates
    ...
    user.save(function(err, doc) {
        // The changes to this doc are complete, move on to the next one.
        stream.resume();
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
}).on('close', function() {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```

Comment: I cant use update, what other options do i have, i have inside of the the user object and array of items, and if the id is say 123 i have to add 2 to it, so i need to enter each one and check who has this id's and such, and more complex things than that even...      I need also to extract the id of each one for later use...

Comment: Thats it! thanks man, if there are even better ones than this, add it guys, The stream approach is async stuff right?

Comment: user.save() is async method, wont it be much slower if i need to save and wait for each one to complete the save?

Comment: Probably, but this is just an example of the concept. You can make the calls to `pause()` and `resume()` however you like (or not at all) to balance speed vs. memory usage.

Comment: So without the pause and resume are we still talking about  a query which not  storing users to the memory, right?

Answer (score 0):

what about [Query Stream](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream_QueryStream) ? , in your example you are getting all users into process memory and then do operations , with stream u just could get singles doc and process it.

Comment: Is the answer above is what im looking for?

Comment: Sure , you could google for it , its better than get all stuff into memory.